# Dynamically determine type of input from controller

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce

I have a custom object with a field named AnswerType that is a Picklist, and has possible values of Picklist, Text or Textarea. Essentially, the client wants to be able to ask the user a question in a form and have the answer be either a select list or a textbox/textarea. I need to be able to dynamically determine which type of input to present based on the AnswerType. I don't think I can use `apex:inputField` because that only works with standard objects and this is a custom object. If I can use an `apex:inputField` I don't know a) what type of variable to use in my controller for b) the value of the `apex:inputField`. If I could, in my controller I would have a variable, such as:

```
Public InputField question;
```

Then in Visualforce:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!question}"/>
```

and let VisualForce determine which type of input to render.

I hope I'm explaining this well. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I'd rather not have to put selectLists and textboxes in my Visualforce page, then render only the one I need. But if that's my only option, I'll do it.

Thanks for any advice anyone has.

Comment: inputFields need to be bound to sobject Fields; no dynamic `value=".."` attribute possible; three fields with rendered= will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your question form's complexity, it could be challenging to use an `<apex:inputField />` tag.

Assuming the custom object you refer to with the field on it of `AnswerType` is the `Question`, you could use something like this in the VF page to handle each type of display output you intend to support.

In this model, each `Question` record has the text of the question and the `DisplayType__c` for driving the UI element shown to gather the response. The `Answer` record is very simple and just has a Long Text Area field on it that captures any answer type in the exact same field, as plain text.

*Note: items not shown - getting the list of questions, storing the answer related to the question, or getting the `selectOptions` if the display type is a picklist. Wrapper classes are used very heavily in the real-life version of the simplified markup below.*

```
<!-- If the question has been defined as a radio button -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="radioPanel" rendered="{!Question.DisplayType__c == 'Radio'}">
    <apex:selectRadio id="selectRadioInput" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectOptions}" />
    </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- If the question has been defined as text input -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="textPanel" rendered="{!(Question.DisplayType__c == 'Text')}">
    <apex:inputText id="textInput" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}" />
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- If the question has been defined as textArea input -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="textPanel" rendered="{!(Question.DisplayType__c == 'Text Area')}">
    <apex:inputTextArea id="textAreaInput" rows="3" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}"  />
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- If the question has been defined as a checkbox input -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="checkboxPanel" rendered="{!Question.DisplayType__c == 'Checkbox'}">
    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxInput" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}" />
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- If the question has been defined as a single picklist -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="picklistPanel" rendered="{!(Question.DisplayType__c == 'Picklist')}" >
    <apex:selectList id="selectListInput" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>  
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- If the question has been defined as a multiselect picklist -->
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="multiPicklistPanel" rendered="{!(Question.DisplayType__c == 'Picklist (Multi-Select)')}" >
    <apex:selectList id="multiPicklist" value="{!Answer.AnswerValue__c}" multiselect="true" size="5">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: and one could stick this all into a component so the main VF page didn't get visually overwhelmed in markup

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark. It is kind of what I suspected, so I will definitely take your recommended approach.